# In ADF Parse activity in Mapping DataFlow how do I set schema dynamically?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My problem is that I have rows with a column of JSON data that takes many different forms.

So I need at way to dynamically set the schema of the output column type. How is that possible?

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to dynamically set the schema in this case.(parse trnasformation)

Comment: Is it possible with Parse activity ? @Aswin

Comment: How about Cast ?

Comment: Can you add your input data and expected output?

Comment: The incomming data is a string that takes the form of JSON. Is it possible to parameterize the schema, so I dont need to express the schema for each type of json object?

Answer (score 0):

> The incomming data is a string that takes the form of JSON. Is it possible to parameterize the schema, so I dont need to express the schema for each type of json object?

As your schema is different for every row(JSON string), dataflow cannot handle various schemas in the rows. Your schema should be same to use the dataflow.

To achieve your requirement, you can try the below workaround. But for this, you need an intermediate storage account, and it will only work when you source dataset is less than 5000 rows.

First give your source dataset to a lookup activity(uncheck **FirstRow**) and it will give its output array like below.

[image]

Give `@range(0, activity('Lookup1').output.count)` expression in the ForEach.

[image]

For the temporary source, create a dummy csv file in the storage account with 1 column and 1 row like below.

[image]

Create a csv dataset for this and give it as copy activity source. In the source settings, add an additional column and give below expression

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[item()].jsonstring
```

[image]

For the sink, create another csv dataset and give below settings. As your JSON strings are dynamic, to create the JSON files dynamically, create a string parameter `filename` in this dataset and use it like below.

[image]

In the copy activity sink, give the `myjson@{add(item(),1)}.json` expression for the same parameter.

[image]

In the mapping, give the below dynamic expression.

```
@json('{

                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",

                                    "mappings": [

                                        {

                                            "source": {

                                                "name": "new",

                                                "type": "String"

                                            },

                                            "sink": {

                                                "type": "String",

                                                "physicalType": "String",

                                                "ordinal": 1

                                            }

                                        }

                                    ],

                                    "typeConversion": true,

                                    "typeConversionSettings": {

                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,

                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false

                                    }

                                }')
```

[image]

Now, debug this pipeline. This pipeline will go through every row of your data, and it will create a JSON file for every JSON string. Later, you can use those as per their schema.

[image]